# Bokeh MultiLine p.add_tools(HoverTool(), renderers = [multiline]) not working

Tags: bokeh, multiline

So when trying to add a HoverTool to a plot, the MultiLine Hover works.

But the problem I am having is, that I have another highlighting Single Line, that I do not want the Hover to act on.
So I wanted to input just the multiline to the renderers keyword

```
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips = [('Name: ', '@Name'),
                                  ('Value', '@Value')],
                      renderers = [multiline]
                     )
```

and I am getting the following error:

ValueError: expected an element of either Auto or List(Instance(Renderer)), got [MultiLine(id='4982e76f-7dda-4d78-b729-240c9a29bdef', ...)]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glyphs (such as `MultiLine`) are more like a description of what to draw. There is a seperate `GlyphRenderer` that takes glyphs and uses them to draw (it can actually have several versions of a glyph to use in different cases, e.g. for selecting and highlighting and decimating). The `renderers` arg of the hover tool expects the `GlyphRenderer`, not the glyph.

If you are using `bokeh.plotting`, then the glyph renderer is returned by the method on the figure:

```
r = plot.multi_line(...) # r is what to configure on the hover tool
```

If you are using the low level `bokeh.models` API then you must already be configuring a `GlyphRenderer` manually for your `MultiLine`. Pass that to the hover tool instead.